# How to get the previous row-text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, row

First of all: I am a SQL beginner and I use SQL Server 2008.

The tables as it is now, is written as:

```
SELECT 
    Transaction.description, Person.name 
FROM 
    Transaction, Person, SystemUser
WHERE 
    Person.personnumber = SystemUser.personnumber 
    AND Transaction.art_ID = SystemUser.art_ID 
ORDER BY 
    Transaction.description
```

where `personnumber` is PK `nvarchar` (could look like `N0890`) where the last numbers of it grows with +1 for every new person.

`art_ID` (Transaction) is PK `smallint`, `art_ID` (SystemUser) is `smallint`, `description` is `nvarchar`.

I want to get the text from the previous row, in the same column, so that I can manipulate the text to be clear and make the result-table look more simple.

Example as it is now:

```
|Transactions       | Persons  |
|-------------------|----------|
|Statistic          | Ursula   |
|Statistic          | Peter    |
|Statistic          | Alan     |
|Settlement         | Christie |
|Settlement         | Tania    |
|Deptor department  | Jack     |
|Economy department | Rickie   |
|Economy department | Annie    |
|Economy department | Tom      |
|Economy department | Seth     |
```

How I want it to be:

```
|Transactions       | Persons  |
|-------------------|----------|
|Statistic          | Ursula   |
|                   | Peter    |
|                   | Alan     |
|Settlement         | Christie |
|                   | Tania    |
|Deptor department  | Jack     |
|Economy department | Rickie   |
|                   | Annie    |
|                   | Tom      |
|                   | Seth     |
```

as in select case when description = description - 1 row then ''

I have searched for examples and every one of them are based on integers, not varchar/nvarchar), and I keep getting errors when i try to do it with `varchars`. Such as With CTE, min() and max().

Do you have any ideas of what function I can use or how to set up the select-statement to do as I want?

Comment: This is normally something done in the 'presentation' layer. How are you presenting this to a user? in Excel?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Actually I am using an online system. In that system, there's a section where you can select and then print out reports. As an programmer, I can go in there and edit the reports. But it is limited, because it's not clear sql server program, it's a tool where you can choose the tables you want to use, link them together, then select the fields you want to use and the add some  constraints. you can not make another instance of the same table. 
You can choose to print out on html, pdf and excel, and then you can't do more than that. It depends on the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use a rank function to identify just one of them:

```
SELECT Transaction.description, Person.name,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Transaction.description ORDER BY Person.name) As R
FROM Transaction, Person, SystemUser
WHERE Person.personnumber = SystemUser.personnumber 
AND Transaction.art_ID = SystemUser.art_ID 
ORDER BY Transaction.description, Person.name
```

Notice the lines you want to see have 1 against them? Use that:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN R=1 THEN Transaction.description ELSE '' END description, 
Person.name
FROM 
(
SELECT Transaction.description, Person.name,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Transaction.description ORDER BY Person.name) As R
FROM Transaction, Person, SystemUser
WHERE Person.personnumber = SystemUser.personnumber 
AND Transaction.art_ID = SystemUser.art_ID 
) Subtable
ORDER BY Transaction.description,  Person.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following SQL should work

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (rowrank INT, description VARCHAR(256), name VARCHAR(256));

INSERT INTO #TempTable (rowrank, description, name)
VALUES

Select RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Transaction.description)
    ,Transaction.description
    ,name
FROM Transaction, Person, SystemUser
WHERE Person.personnumber = SystemUser.personnumber 
AND Transaction.art_ID = SystemUser.art_ID 
ORDER BY Transaction.description

SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN prev.RANK = TT.RANK
        THEN ""
    ELSE TT.Description 
END AS Description,
name 

FROM #TempTable TT
LEFT JOIN #TempTable prev ON prev.rownum = TT.rownum - 1
```